# Adding formula field is suppressing entire records

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, reporting

I'm trying to add a value to my report using an sql expression, or also tried using a database field.  Some of the records on the report will have a match, and some will not.  I want it to display this value where there is a match.  Problem is, when I add this formula or database field, the entire row gets suppressed.  How can I fix this?  Can anyone provide some guidance on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all links in Crystal Reports are inner joins by default.  In this case, where only some records have a match, you need to use a left outer join so as not to null non-matching records.

http://forums.blackbaud.com/forums/t/8825.aspx